# How to have front end and back end use different language?

Tags: admin, locale

I am making a Japanese magento store.  The front end should be Japanese locale.

The back end (admin area) should be in English, at least for my admin user.

It looks like this is not possible to do?  The locale setting seems to affect both front and back end.

(Ideally, I think each admin user should be able to set which language the admin interface appears in to them, as part of their user account settings.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088830/is-it-possible-to-change-magento-backend-language-for-one-user-only

Answer (score 1):

Look at the bottom left of your Admin page.

[image]